# javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm creating a small application using JSF,facing the exception, below is the code for the form.

```
  <h:form>

 <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{transferMB.selectedItems}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Transfer Status" />
      <p:ajax update=":transForm" />
 </h:selectManyCheckbox>

</h:form>
```

exception " javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a follow-up for [issue while loading data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246714/hide-or-show-datatable-primefaces)

As mentioned there, you need to use EL 2.2 for passing parameter inside EL-Expressions. Seems you don't use that.

So we need another way to get this solved:

```
<h:form id="transForm">
    <p:panelGrid columns="1" rendered="#{transferMB.transFormEnabled}">
        <h:outputText value="transForm"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
<h:form id="spreadForm">
    <p:panelGrid columns="1" rendered="#{transferMB.spreadFormEnabled}">
        <h:outputText value="spreadForm"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

and in your corresponding bean:

```
public boolean isTransFormEnabled() {
    if (selectedItems.contains("1")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
public boolean isSpreadFormEnabled() {
    if (selectedItems.contains("2")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling `Boolean-like` values into your rendered attributes.

Example:

```
<p:panelGroup id="group" rendered="{#bean.isOneSelected}">
...
</p:panelGroup>

<p:panelGroup id="group" rendered="{#bean.isTwoSelected}">
...
</p:panelGroup>
```

And for getting values from selectManyMenu. Please check [here](http://www.sitenol.com/select-many-listbox-hselectmanylistbox-in-jsf).

---

Also the rendered tag is a `Boolean` like condition to tell whether a tag should be displayed. You shouldn't need to pass a parameter into that. You should be getting that information from you `transferMB`

Comment: Please see the above post, added code followed by the exception iam facing @Josef E.

Comment: @user3684675 Is there any other way you can get that `needed` value? Maybe have it passed to the been from a hidden field or is that user entered? Because 'rendered' cannot have a parameter passed into it.

Comment: oh..but without passing i cannot check the condition,which checkbox is checked.

Comment: You have an `ajax` tag in your selectmenu. Use that to update, corresponding values in your bean.  I'll edit my answer @user3684675

Comment: but when i researched i came to know that 'rendered' can call other method to check the condition. I think it might be some jar issue but not sure..@Josef E.

Comment: It is not a jar issue. You are calling the method, but you cannot pass parameters into it. Rendered is a boolean-like attribute. @user3684675

Comment: oh ok. then i should see some other way to get the selected checkbox value to know which checkbox have been selected. But one question, if you see controlSelectedValues(..) method it is returning a boolean value.

Comment: +1 for your suggestions and time, i got what u told but how can i pass the selected checkbox value to bean and from their how to pass to controlSelectedValues(..).

Comment: You could create a listener with your `ajax` call **Example** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287115/primefaces-ajax-listener-not-executed-when-process-attribute-is-specified-for-a

Comment: Also try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824178/getting-selected-value-of-a-selectonemenu @user3684675 In addition with last comment